# Noether normalization lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I was looking at the proof of the Noether normalization lemma in the affine case.

To be clear : let $X$ be an affine variety , there exists a finite map $\phi : X \to \mathbb{A}^m$.

In the proof, the authors embedded $X$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$ for some $n$. Then they embedded this affine space in $\mathbb{P}^n$ ,took the closure of $X$ (call that $Y$) in this space and made a projection from a point nor in $Y$, nor in the affine space.

So, they got a map $ \psi : Y \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ which is a finite morphism with the image and that takes $X$ to $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}$.

Iterating that, they got a finite morphism $\phi : Y \to \mathbb{P}^m $ that takes $X$ in $\mathbb{A}^m$, but i can't really see why the restriction to $X$ is still finite with the image.

What am i missing? Is this trivial?

Hope i've been clear about my doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in observing that finiteness is in general not preserved when passing to an open subset of the domain. However, it *is* preserved under base change, so what you need to see is that
$$
X = \mathbb{A}^m \times_{\mathbb{P}^m} Y,
$$
then the map $X \to \mathbb{A}^m$ is just a base change of the finite $Y \to \mathbb{P}^m$.

As to why this is true: $\mathbb{A}^m \to \mathbb{P}^m$ is an open immersion, so the right hand side of the above fibered product is $\phi^{-1} (\mathbb{A}^m)$. To see equality with $X$, consider the case of one projection $\psi$ and observe that the projection $\mathbb{P}^n \setminus\{x\} \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ maps the decomposition
$$\mathbb{P}^{n} = \mathbb{A}^n \cup \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$$
to a similar decomposition of $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't really know what a fibered product is

Comment: Also, can I ask for a counterexample to preservation of finiteness when passing to an open subset of the domain?

Comment: Consider the finite map $\mathbb{A}^1 \coprod \mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^1$. Taking out one point of one of the lines gives an open on which the map is still surjective, but no longer finite onto its image. What's going on: Open immersions are "rarely" finite (only if their complement is also open!), and I just added a second copy of $\mathbb{A}^1$ to not destroy the surjectivity upon passing to the open subset of the domain.

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't see why this map is not finite onto its image.

Comment: On rings it's $k[T] \to k[X] \times k[Y, Y^{-1}]$ sending $T$ to $(X,Y)$. Consider the RHS as $k[T]$-module via this map, we have to see that it is not finitely generated. It's a direct sum of a free $k[T]$-module with $k[T, T^{-1}]$, so it is enough to see that the latter is not finitely generated. This follows by observing that finitely many Laurent polynomials admit a common denominator of the form $T^{-N}$ so lie in the proper submodule $T^{-N} k[T] \subsetneq k[T, T^{-1}]$.